# Unknown flag: --go_opt while regenerating gRPC code

Tags: go, grpc

I followed the gRPC quickstart document in this link https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/ and while regenerating the gRPC code i am getting error ( Unknown flag: --go_opt) as shown below. Tried all the options but not working. It also gives ( Unknown flag: --go-grpc_opt) error.

Command -

```sh
$ protoc \
  --go_out=Mgrpc/service_config/service_config.proto=/internal/proto/grpc_service_config:. \
  --go-grpc_out=Mgrpc/service_config/service_config.proto=/internal/proto/grpc_service_config:. \
  --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
  helloworld/helloworld.proto

Error - Unknown flag: --go_opt
```

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you copy paste the command you run? It looks like you hit this issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc.io/issues/298#issuecomment-656767393 You need to install protoc-gen-go-grpc in your PATH

Comment: [Do not paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: I have already tried github.com/grpc/grpc.io/issues/298#issuecomment-656767393 as it is given in the mentioned link here https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/. This is the command ( cd ../../cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc && go install . )

Comment: can you verify if `protoc-gen-go` or `protoc-gen-go-grpc` binary is present in your PATH?

Comment: I can see protoc-gen-go-grpc folder under grpc-go/cmd

Comment: it doesn't imply it is in the path. 3. prerequisite in the tutorial has this command: `$ export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"` which adds GOPATH/bin to your PATH. When you do `go install` binary will be in your PATH. You can. verify if binary is on your path by using `which` command. ie: `which protoc-gen-go`

Comment: I used command (which protoc-gen-go) and went to the path listed by the command. I can see protoc-gen-go there.

Comment: I also installed protoc-gen-go-grpc but again same error.

Answer (score 9):

I had a same issue. I removed the installed protobuf compiler and reinstalled protobuf compiler with "Install pre-compiled binaries" option in
https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/.

```
sudo apt-get remove protobuf-compiler
$PB_REL="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"
$ curl -LO $PB_REL/download/v3.12.1/protoc-3.12.1-linux-x86_64.zip

$sudo apt install unzip
$unzip protoc-3.12.1-linux-x86_64.zip -d HOME/.local

$export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

Comment: The `_opt` flavor is only supported on newer versions of the compiler. If you don't want to install a newer version than your package manager provides, you can also simply move the `paths=source_relative` into the `--go_out=` section like `--go_out=paths=source_relative:Mpath/to/file.proto=desired/go/package:<outdir>`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems common with a few different pain points, so I'll add a answer that might be useful for a highlighting a bunch of problems:

1. Older versions of the compiler don't have the `_opt` flag
2. `protoc` has a `--foo_opt` flag [only](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1328) if you also specify a `--foo_out` flag
3. A few tutorials *might* be using incorrect `export` commands, so verify that the `protoc` and other binaries such `protoc-gen-go-grpc` are actually added to the path (there are many ways to check/modify the `PATH` variable depending on the system, adding basic resources to get started on [Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/341192/how-can-i-display-the-contents-of-an-environment-variable-from-the-command-promp) or [Unix](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/bb/cs348/www-S08/unix_path.html))

Comment: 1. did it for me: `protoc --version >= 3.12` solved the `_opt` error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, then I tried like this:

```
protoc --proto_path=helloworld --go_out=paths=source_relative:. -I. helloworld/*.proto
```

Answer (score -4):

You are missing the 4th line: `--go_opt=paths=source_relative \`.

Comment: Yes but this is not the problem. You should add this as a comment to the initial question.

Comment: @dcow This IS the problem. Adding the missing line and the compilation is passed.